# Bamboo plan using previous version of repo file.

Tags: bamboo

I updated a resource file for a build, pushed the changes, verified they are updated in stash and ran my bamboo plan. The log shows that the contents of the file are the same as before the push.  I checked the artifacts and see the correct version of the file there.  I have not changed anything in Miscellaneous Tab (should I clean working directory after each build?).

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Have you verified in the log file thata the check-out is working correctly? And/or that it's the right branch you set in your repo?

Comment: Had to make sure clean working directory was checked for each stage.

Comment: Ugh, won't that slow down your builds though? I've seen that recommendation elsewhere and it's one of those "yeah, but that misses the whole point of the feature and if it's causing issues something else is wrong (including a bug in Bamboo)"

Comment: Yes, but there is the saved disk space and for the present the additional test integration into the builds is more important than the overall speed.